# Is it possible to use metric values with equal tags only once

Tags: datadog, datadog-dashboard

I have a metric in datadog with three different tags: TagA, TagB and TagC.

When I visualize the metric values in a dashboard, I want that only one metric value will be used with equal tag values.

Example:
These are the metric values:

```
1. TagA:v1; TagB:v2; TagC:v3
2. TagA:v2; TagB:v2; TagC:v3
3. TagA:v1; TagB:v2; TagC:v3
4. TagA:v3; TagB:v2; TagC:v3
```

Then I only want the values 1, 2 and 4 to be considered for visualization.

Thanks for any answers

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question: do you mean you want to display only one point of your metric for each combination of tag values?
Could you give more context about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to visualize the metric in a pie chart.
The formula used is
 
`sum:search.resultsDifference{env:$ENVIRONMENT.value} by {TagA,TagB}.as_count()`

But I only want to consider metric values once when they have the same tags, because in this case they are duplicates.
Does this help?

Comment: If values in series 1 & 3 have the same tags and timestamps, then they'll be aggregated in Datadog's internal data storage and can't be split apart. Is there another tag (e.g., TagD) that's actually different and you can filter based on? FWIW, there are many options for advanced filtering if you have a tag value you can exclude: https://docs.datadoghq.com/metrics/advanced-filtering/